# ListView Grid Item Holding not working

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

I'm using a ListView with more than one DataTemplate. I'm trying to detect when the user clicks on an Item to show a Flyout.
GridItem_Holding is never called.

XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myKey1">
        <Grid Holding="GridItem_Holding">
        ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myKey2">
        <Grid Holding="GridItem_Holding">
        ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
private void GridItem_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Where does the Holding event(?) come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<Grid x:Name="GridListItem" Holding="Grid_Holding">
```

Comment: And what it does ? Mind explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered IsHoldingEnabled on Grid or children? Holding event is not triggered unless it is set true.

Comment: I've set IsHoldingEnabled  on a Grid with no childs and nothing happened. I moved to Tapped and all works fine

Comment: I believe IsHoldingEnabled default value of ListView and Grid is already true unless you set it to false